# Will calling .Any() in a lazy loaded collection navigation property enumerate the property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following entities:

```
public class Principal
{
   [Key,DatabaseGenerated]
   public int ID{ get; set; }

   [Key,DatabaseGenerated]
   public virtual ICollection<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
}

public class Dependent
{
   [Key]
   public int PrincipalID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("PrincipalID")]
   public virtual Principal Principal { get; set; }
}
```

In the following scenario:

```
var principal = db.Principals.First();

if( principal.Dependents.Any()){
  // Do stuff
}
```

will the call to .Any retrieve the dependent entities or is EF smart enough to do an Exists in the store instead of retrieving the related records and doing .Any() on the enumerable?

Comment: @eranotzap: You're misunderstanding the question.  He's asking what query it will run.  EF will not lie.

Comment: @SLaks True, although you *could* use the logger of the context to see what query is run in the two cases, rather than expecting the results to differ, to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `Dependents` navigation-property is not an `IQueryable` (and EF doesn't support `IQueryable` on navigation-properties), once loaded, the entire navigation-property data is executed and materialized and further LINQ calls will be called using `Enumerable.Any` (Linq-to-Objects).

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no way that can happen.

`Dependents` is an `ICollection<T>`, not an `IQueryable<T>`, so `Any()` is the standard LINQ-to-Objects `Any()`.

EF will load all of the objects as soon as you first get the property.

Answer (score 1):

It will retrieve all of the dependent entities.

The property is an `ICollection`, meaning it implements `IEnumerable` not `IQueryable`.  This means that `Any` is just iterating the collection in memory (meaning it needs to be lazily loaded) rather than sending an `Expression` to the query provider, letting the query provider do whatever it wants with that `Expression`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do something that *was* executed on the database, you could do something like this:

```
if (db.Principals.Take(1).Any(p => p.Dependents.Any()))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Or assuming you wanted to do something with the first `Principal` only if it has a `Dependent`:

```
var principal =
    db.Principals.Take(1)
    .Where(p => p.Dependents.Any()))
    .SingleOrDefault();

if (principal != null)
{
    // do stuff with principal...
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand. The question is about the Dependents navigation property *after* the principal entity is materialized. Its simplified but imagine passing the principal entity that was retrieved with some logic to another layer. If that other layer did .Any() cause that all it needs to do, would it retrieve all the records (i.e. performance penalty there if it enumerates).

Comment: Sometimes I try to see the question behind the question, but apparently I tried too hard in this case. When you asked "...is EF smart enough to do an Exists...", I inferred that to be the behavior you would prefer. In any case, if you only wish to deal with a `Principal` that has at least one `Dependent`, the procedures I outlined would be a bit more efficient in terms of data retrieval.